# Default template parameters arguments in VC++

Tags: visual-c++, templates, default-value

Does VC++ not support default template parameters arguments? This simple code:

```
template <typename T=int>
class X
{
};

X x;
```

gives me an '`error C2955: 'X' : use of class template requires template argument list`'. No complaints about the template declaration, however.

What am I missing here? Some compiler switch maybe?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you still have to specify an empty template list, or use a typedef:

```
template <typename T=int>
class X
{
};

X<> x;

typedef X<> XX;
XX x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question has already been [answered very well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495987/default-template-parameters-arguments-in-vc/1495999#1495999). However, I want to point out that, whenever you ask yourself whether it's you or the compiler, take a code snipped to [Comeau's online compiler](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/). Comeau is widely acknowledged as the most standard-conforming C++ compiler around and has excellent error messages.

BTW, surprisingly the compiler doesn't cost much, so if you want the convenience to have it on your machine, the price shouldn't be in your way.

Comment: Unfortunately the online compiler referenced above is no longer available. It appears that Comeau may no longer be in the compiler business, with the website having been converted to a blog/news aggregator.